# How To Read Serial Data With NodeMCU

Tags: serial, nodemcu

I am trying to change leds status via serial port screen. Here is my code but it's not reading anything from serial port screen. I got leds on D1 and D2 pins.

```
void setup() {
pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(115200);

}

void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int point = Serial.read();
 if(point == 1)
{
digitalWrite(5,!5); 
}
else if(point == 2)
{
 digitalWrite(4,!4);
}

}
```

Comment: `!4` means `0` and so does `!5`

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't doing what you expect because of a few issues.  As echo_salik says you are only ever turning off the output pins.  If you want to toggle the values then its probably easiest to store the value in a bool and use that to control the LED.

I think - and I may be wrong - that you are pressing the one and two keys and expecting that to work.  When you press the 1 key `Serial.read()` will return 49 and 2 will return 50.  These are the ASCII values for the keys you are pressing.

Its advisable to test to see if there is any data available to read on the serial port.  `read()` will return -1 if there is no data.

```
void loop() 
{
  if (Serial.available())
  {
    int point = Serial.read();
    switch (point)
    {
      case 1:
        digitalWrite(5,HIGH); // Not !5 use High and Low
        break;
      case 2:
        digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
        break;
      case 3:
        digitalWrite(5,LOW); // Not !5 use High and Low
        break;
      case 4:
        digitalWrite(5,LOW); // Not !5 use High and Low
        break;
    }  // End of switch
  }  // End of if
  delay(50);  // I have no idea why, but most programs of this sort have a delay in.  (Hope someone explains to me too)
}  // End of function
```

(A switch statement is a more efficient way of doing a number of if elses)

One thing you might want to consider is the values you are checking against.  `Serial.read()` is returning a value between -1 and 255.  It is not returning the key you pressed.  If you want to change it to work with keys then you can do it by changing the case statements that are checking integers `case 1:` to ones that are checking characters i.e. `case '1':`.